# TimeOut exception not getting triggered in Kafka producer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm using Kafka producer send() method with callback . most of the time (around 90%) we are able to produce the record without any issue but intermittently, after calling .send() method the Java thread is getting stuck while trying to produce . we are using default timeout values but exception of any kind is not getting triggered (we are expecting timeout exception or something but it's just stuck trying to produce).

***BELOW IS THE CODE SNIPPET***

```
kafkaProducer.send(new ProducerRecord(topic, key, kafkaMsg), new Callback(){
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata,Exception e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    isSuccess = true;
                    //MessageLogger.logMessageString("INFO","Published partition details :: "+TransactionID,
                    MessageLogger.logMessageStringOld("INFO","Published partition details :: "+TransactionID, 
                       "topic -> "+ metadata.topic()+"\n" +
                       "partition -> "+metadata.partition()+"\n"+
                       "offset -> "+metadata.offset());
                } else {
                    //MessageLogger.logMessageString("ERROR", "Exception in publish message",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    MessageLogger.logMessageStringOld("ERROR", "Exception in publish message",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    isSuccess = false;
                }
            }
        });
        kafkaProducer.flush();
        kafkaProducer.close();
```

I tried to play with some timeout properties but no luck
**example :
kafkaProdConfig.put("max.block.ms", 60000);
kafkaProdConfig.put("request.timeout.ms", 30000);**

Could someone provide insight on this please?

Comment: When you say "the Java thread is getting stuck trying to produce" does the producer keep retying until eventually the message is successfully sent? I'm trying to understand what you want to achieve i.e. is this part of a test where you want to see how the producer handles TimeoutExceptions?

Comment: Hi @JessicaVasey , No it's not retrying ... I believe the producer trying to get metadata from kafka and it's stuck there at the first try itself . it didn't made any retry (since , my producer config is set to "0" retry ) . it is not part of test , it's happening in our production (real time) .

to add more , mostly we are able to produce records without any issue and rarely we are facing this issue where producer is not even throwing any exception/errors if it can't produce the record ... it's just stuck literally

Comment: Hi @Misubushi, what version of Kafka are you using?

Comment: @JessicaVasey , I'm using Kafka-clients 3.3.2 for Kafka producer and our kafka environment is Confluent Platform 6.2 .